# MSVC - Suppress template being compiled with messages

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have an application that uses numerous templates and template specializations, and during MSVC compilation many messages are output showing how the templates are being compiled. This makes for an incredibly difficult time finding an actual compilation error. These messages are not output when the application is compiled on Linux using g++.

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\map(382)
: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std:
:_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,true>>::insert<std::pair<std::string,uint64_t>>(_Valty &&)' being compiled
    with
    [
        _Kty=std::string
,            _Ty=size_t
,            _Pr=std::less<std::string>
,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,size_t>>
,            _Valty=std::pair<std::string,uint64_t>
    ]
```

Is there a way can I suppress these more or less useless messages? Or possibly lower the verbosity setting? I've tried looking at [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx) but I'm not sure if there is a flag that relates to the messages I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is related to an warning (or error) with a specific template instantiation. If it is a warning, you could suppress it (via #pragma warning, or project settings), and this message would also go away. Or, you could fix the cause of the warning. There is no way to suppress this message without also suppressing the warning, because without it, the warning doesn't make much sense.